# Dynamic / Async Component Render

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am quite new to VueJS and have been playing around with the framework for a couple of days.

I am building a sort of dashboard with a widget based look and feel and the problem I have is that when the user adds a lot of widgets to the dashboard, problems arise on the loading of the page since the widgets make simultaneous calls to the API's to retrieve subsets of data.

To give you a better understanding of what I am doing, the concept is the below. (This is a brief idea to keep the code clean and simple).

Home.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="Home">
    <h1>Homepage</h1>
    <div v-for="w in widgets">
        <component :is="widget"></component>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Home',
  mounted() {

    for (var i = 0; i < availableWidgets; i++) {
        widgets.push(availableWidgets);
    }

  },
};
</script>
```

Widget 1

```
<template>
  <div class="Widget1">
    <span>Widget 1</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'Widget1',
  mounted() {
    //Get data from API and render
  },
};
</script>
```

Widget 2

```
<template>
  <div class="Widget2">
    <span>Widget 2</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'Widget2',
  mounted() {
    //Get data from API and render
  },
};
</script>
```

As you can see, I am sort of loading the widgets and adding them dynamically depending on what the user has in his dashboard.

The problem I have is that Widget 1 and Widget 2 (in my case there are like 20-30 widgets), will be making API calls and this works fine when 1 or 2 widgets are loaded. But once the page grows a lot and there will be like 10 widgets on the page, everything starts lagging.

What would you suggest to do to make this more performant? Is it possible to allow once component to load at a time before loading the second component and so on? I was thinking of adding async calls, but that would not stop the components from being loaded at the same time?

Looking forward to your feedback and help that you could provide.

Comment: Nope, async calls shouldn't break your code

Comment: hmm but async calls would not solve the issue solely..

Comment: They'd definitely make your code faster. You could try it out and then follow up here with the results

Answer (score 0):

A common pattern would be to have the first render be without data, then re-render whenever your data comes in. The browser will make sure that not too many network requests run at the same time, so you should not have lag perse from that. You just perceive lag, because your component does not render until the data loads.

I would suggest using something like [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios), which uses promises and makes it easy to create asynchronous http requests while still keeping your code readable.

```
<template>
  <div class="widget graph">
    <div v-if="loading">
      <span>Loading...</span>
      <img src="assets/loader.svg">
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <!-- Do whatever you need to do whenever data loads in -->
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'WidgetGraph',

  data () {
    return {
      loading: true,
      error: null,
      graphData: {}
    }
  },

  created () {
    this.loadData();
  },

  methods: {
    loadData () {
      return axios.get(...).then((data) => {
        this.loading = false;
      }).catch(() => {
        this.error = 'Something went wrong.... Panic!';
        this.loading = false;
      });
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```